# Making a list in the property

Tags: c#, collections

I have a list like that.

```
bread.BreadAdd(new Bread("DF6", "8", 16, 500));  
bread.BreadAdd(new Bread("ZER6D23", "5", 8, 1000));
```

As I understood, I need to create a code in the bread class, but furthermore I have no idea is has to be in the property?  If so, where exactly?

edit: uups. I wrote it wrong. it has to be in a function.

Comment: Could you please post the full code and assignment text you have been given?

Comment: The way you worded it, it isn't easy for an advanced programmer either. What is `BreadAdd()`? Is that the code you have to write? What's up with the property?

Answer (score 1):

Can be something like this:

```
using SCG = System.Collections.Generic;
public class Bread {
   public class Bread(string name,  string version, int foodValue, int weight) {
      //     ...
   }
}

public class Breads {
   private readonly SCG.List breads = new SCG.List();
   public void AddBread(Bread bread) {
      breads.Add(bread);
   }
   public SCG.IEnumerable Breads {
      get { return breads; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below.. You can create a method to add it to a private List variable and then expose it via property or you can have a setter for BreadList property and call `breadClass.BreadList.Add((new Bread("DF6", "8", 16, 500));`. Either option should be fine.

```
public class BreadClass
{
    private List<Bread> lstbread;

    public List<Bread> BreadList
    {
        get
        {
            return bread;
        }
    }

    public void BreadAdd(Bread bread)
    {
        lstbread.Add(bread)
    }
}
```

Comment: I meaned in a function...my fault

Comment: The code above uses function to add to List..Isn't that what u want?

Comment: actually this is not what i want. i didn't explain it correctly. what i want to do is. I have a list. and i want to put it in a function so that i can use is on main.cs

Comment: I still don't understand...  Can u explain step by step or something?

Comment: allright. ok lets give an another example. I have a list of computers. with a code, harddisc, memory and so on. so i have a make a program that user can see all of the list of computers or (if he want) buy it. this is a console app. by the way. so what i need to do first. creating  2 classes. first class need to shows overview or summary. and what is that? 1- shows list of computers 2- shows computers by harddisc capacity and so on. the second class is Pcshop class: this is the class where we can put the functions and lists. what i can't figure it out how to show the list.